# Encrypt and decrypt a string in android

Tags: android

Hi I want to encrypt a string in android inorder to store and later for showing I have to decrypt it. Is it possible to do md5 hashing or any other hashing in android.
Please provide me an example.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773363/java-android-url-encrypting

Comment: **Hashing is not encryption**

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Read this article [here->(How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml)](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml). It is pretty much what you want. The technique there uses `.getInstance("AES");` If you want MD5 just replaces the AES with MD5.

Comment: A nice example. You can store blobs in the db. This way it is faster and the db is smaller. http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesString.html

Comment: @Benny Tjia above Link broken

Comment: The original link is broken.

Comment: The link of How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.html is not available

Comment: Its available on wayback archive : [Check this Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120318012218/http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml)

Answer (score 3):

The javax.crypto package does everything you need

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

`android.util.Base64` encoding is good enough if you want to store something e.g. in a share preferences file:

Here is what I do:

Storing:

```
public void saveSomeText (String text) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    if (Utils.isEmpty( text ))
        text = null;
    else
        text = Base64.encodeToString( text.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT );
    editor.putString( "some_text", text );
    editor.commit();
}
```

Retrieval:

```
public String getSomeText () {
    String text = prefs.getString( "some_text", null );
    if (!Utils.isEmpty( passwd )) {
        text = new String( Base64.decode( text, Base64.DEFAULT ) );
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: no offence, but encoding and encryption are two different things with different purposes. [Check this](http://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [MAHEncryptorLibrary](https://github.com/hummatli/MAHEncryptorLib)

Sample:

- For encryption

  ```
  MAHEncryptor mahEncryptor = MAHEncryptor.newInstance("This is sample SecretKeyPhrase");
  String encrypted = mahEncryptor.encode("This is MAHEncryptorLib java sample");
  ```
- For decryption

  ```
  MAHEncryptor mahEncryptor = MAHEncryptor.newInstance("This is sample SecretKeyPhrase");
  String decrypted = mahEncryptor.decode("4Vi86K/JL9gKclQahacrKLrEZL6/0vOpS4yPVm1hSLhhDsCMJTyd4A==");
  ```

Answer (score -1):

When You want to encrypt a string on one side and decrypt it on other side the use this code its working good.Just copy this code and run in you eclipse, it will solve your problem

*Encryption Method for String*

```
    final int shift_key = 4; //it is the shift key to move charcter, like if i have 'a' then a=97+4=101 which =e and thus it changes
    String plainText = "adhami piran"; 
    char character; 
     char ch[]=new char[plainText.length()];//for storing encrypt char
   for (int iteration = 0; iteration < plainText.length(); iteration++)
            {
                    character = plainText.charAt(iteration); //get characters
                    character = (char) (character + shift_key); //perform shift
              }     ch[iteration]=character;//assign char to char array
     String encryptstr = String.valueOf(ch);//converting char array to string
     Toast.makeText(this, "Encrypt string is "+ encryptstr Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

*Decrypting Method for String*

```
   for(int i=0;i<encryptstr.length();i++)
     {
        character=str.charAt(i);
        character = (char) (character -shift_key); //perform shift
            ch[i]=character;
     }
 Stirng decryptstr = String.valueOf(ch);
     Toast.makeText(this, "Decrypted String is "+decryptstr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```