# How to encrypt url in android?

Tags: android, encryption, url-encoding

When i decompile my apk i saw that anyone can see the url I'm connecting to.The api key that i'm using is also easily accessible.So is there any way to encrypt the String url so when someone try to sneak it there won't be any proper string or api mentioned?

Comment: This question has already an answere here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734844/how-to-url-encode-in-android and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Comment: Are looking for encoding or encrypting ?

Comment: After visiting above url i think my need is encryption.

Comment: For url encrypt see this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5773923/5539802

Comment: You cannot "encrypt" the URL, because the Android needs to use that URL. There is no way around that. You need to design the API in such a way that knowing the URL doesn't lead to anything useful, because the attack might need to log in and then they could only see their own data. It is not clear who you want to protect this from and why.